# Index has incorrect page numbers

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm building an index via a macro, and after a little bit, the page numbers start to get wonky.  At first, they are correct, but as we go deeper in the document, they start getting offset.

I have a hunch it's because the code I'm using uses a range (`.Index.MarkEntry Range:=theRange ...`), and the page of the *end* of the range is where the page number comes from.

How can I make sure that the page number the index uses, is the page that has the first character in the range (does that make sense? Whatever page the entry starts on, is the page I want to use).

Here's my (truncated for relevance) code:

```
Sub Find_Definitions()

Dim myDoc   As Word.Document
Dim oRng As Word.Range, rng As Word.Range, rngXE As Word.Range, tempHold As Word.Range
Dim addDefinition$, findText$, editedDefinition$
Dim meanTypes() As Variant
Dim rngEdited
Dim y&
Dim bFound  As Boolean

meanTypes = Array(Chr(150) & " means", Chr(151) & " means", "- means", Chr(150) & " meaning", Chr(151) & " meaning", "- meaning")

Set myDoc = ActiveDocument
bFound = True

Call Clear_Index

For y = LBound(meanTypes) To UBound(meanTypes)
'Loop through the document
Set oRng = myDoc.Content
Set rngXE = oRng.Duplicate
With oRng.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .ClearAllFuzzyOptions
    '.Text = findText
    .Text = meanTypes(y)
    .MatchCase = False
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
End With                     'orng.find

Do While bFound
    bFound = oRng.Find.Execute
    If bFound Then
        Set rngXE = oRng.Paragraphs(1).Range.Duplicate
        rngXE.Select

        ' Here's where I could check the text, and see if it starts with Roman numerals.
        editedDefinition = Check_For_Roman_Numerals(rngXE, findText)

        If editedDefinition <> "" Then    'If editedDefinition is empty, that means there's no definition to add to the index
            Set rngEdited = rngXE.Duplicate
            With rngEdited
                .moveStart unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=x
                .Select
‘ This next line is my idea that the range’s page number is being used, so I just wanted to print it to see.
                Debug.Print rngEdited.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)
            End With         'rngEdited

            myDoc.Indexes.MarkEntry Range:=rngEdited, entry:=editedDefinition, entryautotext:=editedDefinition

        End If               ''editedDefinition <> ""


        oRng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        oRng.Start = oRng.Paragraphs(1).Range.End
        oRng.End = myDoc.Content.End

        rngEdited.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        rngEdited.End = myDoc.Content.End
    '    Set rngXE = Nothing
    End If                   'bFound
Loop
bFound = True
Next y

TheEnd:
Set rng = Nothing
myDoc.Indexes(1).Update
MsgBox ("Added all definitions.")

End Sub
```

I'm thinking what I'll need to do is to "tighten up" the `editedRange`, so it ends on the same page? But if a definition spans a page break, I want to use the smaller of the page numbers that it appears on (the first one).

Thanks for any ideas/tips/thoughts.

Comment: Just collapse the Range to its starting point before creating the Index entry...

Comment: @CindyMeister - Would that mean to do `RngEdited.Start = oRng.paragraphs(1).Range.End`?  I'm still wrapping my head around how word uses ranges, and appreciate your help!

Comment: There's a Collapse method for the Range object. Think of it like pressing the Left (or right) arrow key when you have a seleciton...

Comment: @CindyMeister - Ah! I added `rngEdited.collapse wdCollapseStart` right before `myDoc.Indexes.MarkEntry ....` and it seems to be working.  Edit: Nevermind, it's still returning incorrect page numbers. Hm.

Comment: @CindyMeister - am I missing something? I added `rngEdited.collapse wdCollapseStart` before adding to the index, but to no avail. Do I need to tweak the `rngEdited.Collapse wdCollapseEnd` that occurs after `End If`?

Comment: @CindyMeister - Ah, I figured out what was going on. After adding things to my Index, since the {XE} fields are visible, they created some extra pages when pushing some data over.  If I made the XE fields not-visible, the pages are correct. Thanks for the `.Collapse` suggestion, if you want, you can make that an answer and I'll mark it for you.  Thanks always for your excellent help!

Comment: Hah! That was the first thing that came to my mind, but then I started reading...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, when the page numbers in an Index don't match with what you expect it's because the document is displaying content that won't be in the printed result. This affects the pagination on-screen, "pushing" content "down" in the document. Most often, the reason is field codes, which can be suppressed by pressing Alt+F9 until the field results display.

This approach does not work for XE (index markers) and some other field types, as well as hidden text, however. They display whenever the display of "Hidden" text is allowed. Depending on the settings in File/Options/Display/"Always show these formatting marks on the screen" clicking the "backwards P" button in the Ribbon's Home tab may or may not turn them off. If it does not, then you have to go into options to togge the display, or create a macro to do this and run it as required.

The other possible reason is that the programmatically generated XE field was inserted at the end of a long range of text that broke to another page, instead of being on the page where the text starts. In order to ensure the field is the start, rather than the end of a Range, collapse the Range to its starting point:

```
rngEdited.Collapse wdCollapseStart
```